# vscode code extension java test runner neither shows a message nor a stack trace

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit5

I want to see my Junit message and stack trace inside Java Test Report window when I run a test. This window is part of the vscode extension called Java Test Runner.

When I run a test I can see if the test passes or fails. the result is N/A (not acquired) in both stack trace and message body.

I'm trying to find out why my java test runner can't display message or stacktrace inside the java test report. That's where I get stuck.

I've tried to run the test with `"java.test.log.level": "verbose"` in the settings.json file of java test runner. But I see no difference in the java test report. This step is based on a post of rohinwork: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/702#issuecomment-492992483

Here is a basic Junit code class to troubleshoot my issue.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }

}
```

- **my software**: I'm using the latest version of vscode 1.51.1 (at the moment of writing this post), the latest java adoptOpenJDK 14.0.2+12 (the latest recommended at the moment of writing this post.
- **my setup:** I'm using visual studio code in portable mode locally on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, the test report is only used to show the failed message or stack trace.

Given the example code you give, `assertTrue( true );` won't fail the test. Since the test is passed, there is no failed message/stack trace. That's why you saw `N/A` in test report.

BTW, if you want to see some logs of your own program, they are printed in the debug console. For example, if your test code is written as

```java
@Test
void testMessage() throws {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

You will see the `Hi` in Debug Console:
[image]

#### Update

There is an issue which is considering to follow the execution place of the Java Debugger: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1106

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem of my stack trace. But that only covers part of my question. My other problem is that there's no message in the java test reporter. If I look to other example on the [official website description of the extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing). I can see it is not necessary to use it anyway. I can make use of syntax tests to point out mistakes in my code base.

Comment: Only the failed cases will have error messages / stack traces. If your test cases are passed, there will be no message / stack traces show in the report for that passed case.

Comment: Can you give a small example function others can use to see how message works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, I guess I got your idea now. Just checked about the current implementation, the message will only show for TestNG framework. That's why you cannot see it.